# CSS [custom?] attributes

Tags: css, firefox, xul

```
radio[pane] {
 list-style-image: url("jar:resource:///chrome/classic.jar!
         /skin/classic/browser/preferences/Options.png");
}

radio[pane="prefpane-appearance"] {
 -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 32px, 32px, 0px);
}
radio[pane="prefpane-appearance"]:hover,
radio[pane="prefpane-appearance"][selected="true"] {
 -moz-image-region: rect(32px, 32px, 64px, 0px);
}
```

Can anyone explain a syntax of this css, particularly what is `pane`.. I couldn't find such attribute for radio element in context of XUL. So I guess it's some custom attribute? If it is, then how it is evolving through the lines, first declaration, then several assignments? It has also `selected`, which means can have multiple custom attributes?
How can those attributes be used later?

Comment: Those are not assignments, those are attribute (value) matches.  AFAIK `selected` is a standard, not custom attribute.  The most selective match will be applied first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brackets selector (`[]`) selects by attribute.

The following matches any image with the `title` attribute set to something:

```
img[title] { /* stuff */ }
```

The following matches any image whose `src` attribute is `foo.png`:

```
img[src="foo.png"] { /* stuff */ }
```

So your example rules match respectively:

1. `radio` elements with a `pane` attribute;
2. `radio` elements whose `pane` attribute is set, and is equal to `prefpane-appearance`;
3. hovered `radio` elements whose `pane` attribute is set, and is equal to `prefpane-appearance`;
4. `radio` elements whose `pane` attribute is set and is equal to `prefpane-appearance`, and whose `selected` attribute is set and is equal to `true`.

Comment: @zneak: so for example this expression will negate selector? window:not([active="true"]) ?

Comment: Yeah: it will match `window` element whose `active` attribute is either not set or not equal to `true`.